# Get rid of Border on Page

Tags: .net, wpf, border

If I set the Border Style on a page I get a Border on the Page.
If I take away the Style then the Border goes away (but so does the style).
But I need that Border Style for several borders used in the Page.
How do I have a Border Style but not have the Border on the Page?

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Steelblue" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3,2.7,3,2.7" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3" />
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid> 
        <TabControl>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to take off the border style on the Page but have other controls use that Border style?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis I don't know how to be more clear. I don't want the Border on the overall Page. I am getting a Border on the overall Page that I do not want.  I want the Border Style on the Page but do not want the Border on the overall Page.

Comment: So does it mean, you don't want the "default" Border style that you are getting and you want to restyle it? Or, you want to set a style on the Page Resource level but you don't want to have a Border on the Page at all?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis Border and Border Style are not the same thing.  What part of I don't want the Border on the overall Page is not clear?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language. If I understood it correctly, yeah that was my first thought of moving your Style in Grid.Resources that's why I was asking if you wanted the style to be applied for other controls except for the Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Page` is using a border to render itself and you don't want it to style that, then either define it at a lower level, such as in your `Grid.Resources` instead of `Page.Resources`.

Or instead of targeting every border with

```
  <Style TargetType="Border">
```

Instead use

```
  <Style x:Key="myBorderStyle">
```

And apply them individually on every border with

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource myBorderStyle}">
```